# is "ZonedDateTime not defined error" a bug?

Tags: zoneddatetime, bixby

when trying to create a new DateTime object from millis since epoch I call:

```
var dateTime = new ZonedDateTime(searchRegion.locality.centroid, [millisSinceEpoch]};
```

I get an error: ReferenceError: "ZonedDateTime" is not defined.

What might be the reason for that? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you missed the `require` step.

```
  var dates = require('dates')
  var t = new dates.ZonedDateTime(searchRegion.locality.centroid, [millisSinceEpoch]);
```

FYI, there is a typo in your code at the end, it should be `)` not `}`

Please try and let us know if it works!

Comment: works! thanks. Additionally ones you have 't' and you want to store it in a model of type DateTime return it as: ``` return t.getDateTime();```